# Hi, I just want to know if it's okay to use require_once twice on the same page with a different file (of course). for example

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once 'db_connect';
require_once 'another_file';
?>
```

is this feasible?
sorry... I'm just new.

thanks for the answer in advance folks!

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: why wouldent it be?

Comment: .................................?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes. make sure you include the .php file extensions

Comment: That is a comment, not answer.

Comment: @JesseSchokker `yes` and `no` are answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally okay, as many files as you want :)